# Google maps api,Postgis,Multipolygon

Tags: api, google-maps, polygon, postgis

PostGis WKT format of Multipolygon is:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(
((20.229 39.409,20.2241 39.401,20.220 39.410,20.229 39.409)),
((20.209 39.407,20.223 39.400,20.211 39.402,20.209 39.4076))
)
```

Google Maps api v3 Polygon is:

```
var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
  ];
```

The question is:
Can i create a multipolygon in google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS supports a number of output formats directly:

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch08.html

*See the ST_As*() funcs.

The Google Maps API supports a number of these as well (SVG, KML, etc.). You should try using a format that both speak. Now I'm not sure if Google Maps accepts multipolygons in any of these formats. But you could always use the [ST_Simplify()](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_Simplify.html) func.

Answer (score 0):

```
var multipolygon=[
[new google.maps.LatLng(x1,y1),new google.maps.LatLng(x2,y2),new google.maps.LatLng(x3,y3)],
.
.
.
[new google.maps.LatLng(x4,y4),new google.maps.LatLng(x5,y5),new google.maps.LatLng(x6,y6)]
];
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to build your shapes by hand since the data's already in PostGIS. Just query PostGIS and have it output the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old, but I was just working on the same thing, trying to create MultiPolygons from GeoJSON files in Google Maps, so thought I would share.

Basically, no, you can't.  But you can create a workaround.

First create something to manage the individual sub-polygons (object, array, etc).  Then populate that object with each portion of the multipolygon.  Then you can treat the sub-polygons as a group, via custom methods or iteration through them.

See http://www.alecbennett.com/projects/loadgeojson for a quick demo of "MultiPolygon" highlighting on hover in Google Maps v3.  Data is loaded from a GeoJSON file, so would be a similar approach to the WKT version.